# entity framework ConnectionTimeout not work

Tags: entity-framework, connection-timeout

I am using entity framework 6.0, and here is how I set the connection timeout:

```
DbContext cc = new DbContext("Data Source=VLT180;Initial Catalog=VISTAIT;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXXXXXX;Password=XXXXX;Connect Timeout=6");

cc.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("select * from table1");
```

but this does not work, when I disconnect my network, the code will hang at the "ExecuteSqlCommand" method infinitely. if I reconnect my network, it works correctly as expected.

I am using the latest entity framework: 6.1.3

Is there any clue?

Comment: Any database related operation will hang there, it seems the database connection timeout does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your Context must look like

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
   public Context(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
   {
   }

   public DbSet<Quote> Quote { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can execute raw sql as follows

```
using (var context = new Context()) 
{ 
    var quotes = context.Quote.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Quote").ToList(); 
}
```

You execute sql on the dbset Quote.